# Turn On or Off Mobile Data using command for Android <= 5.0

Tags: android, adb

How can you turn on or turn off Mobile data using adb command.

I have use the following command -

'''adb shell su -c svc data enable'''

'''adb shell su -c svc data disable'''

The following commands works perfectly for android version greater that 5.0.

For android version <= 5.0 I'm actually getting an error in terminal stating large amount of data is been transferred for the function call.

Can someone please help out and do not mark the question as duplicate before even reading the description

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is only remotely related to Python.

Comment: i don't see any relation with `python` in your question.